# jQuery: How to test if select is changed or form is submitted?

Tags: jquery

How to do  this ? Because I don't want write the same code twice for : `$('select').change(function(){})` or `$('form').submit(function(){})`

**EDIT : My goal**

I have a first form who permit users to enter a code (4 numbers) of a category. When they begin to write in the field, an AJAX request complete a select with the categories names who correspond to the code written by users. After this, if they have a right category (found in database) and they press enter of their keyboard or if they have chose a category in the select, I want to make a form with some values of the database who corespond to the choosen category (get by another AJAX request). But i don't know how to test if they submit the form when they press Enter (submit button is hidden) or if they select a category in the select.

HTML CODE

```
<div class="page-formulaire">
    <form method="post" action="#" id="formulaire-uf">
        <div id="recherche-uf">
            <label>Chose your category </label><br>
            <input type="text" id="uf" maxlength="4" /><br><br>
            <span id="compteur"></span>
            <select name="uf" id="uf-resultat">
                <option selected="selected" id="option-vide"></option>
            </select>

            <div id="uf-erreur"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <form method="post" action="#" id="formulaire-maj">

        <div id="formulaire">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Morning: </legend>
                <label>Man : </label><input type="text" name="hommes-matin" id="hommes-matin" class="input"/><br>
                <label>Women : </label><input type="text" name="femmes-matin" id="femmes-matin" class="input"/><br>
                <label>Twice : </label><input type="text" name="indiff-matin" id="indiff-matin"/><br>
            </fieldset><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn-bleu">
            <button type="button" id="annuler" onclick="window.location='formulaire.php'">Cancel</button>

        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: `$('select, form').on('change submit', handler)`???

Comment: If both are executing the same code why don't you put the common code in a function, and have `change` and `submit` execute that function.

Comment: @A. Wolff if i want test you code, I do this ? :      $('select, form').on('change submit', handler){
      console.log("test ok");
     }

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w928794j/

Answer (score 0):

Given a simple `select`

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Hello</option>
        <option value=2>Hello2</option>
</select>
```

and using jQuerys **[.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** handler, you can actually "listen" for multple events.

```
$('select, form').on('change submit', function(){
   alert("hi"); 
});
```

The first parameter in the `.on()` method is a String or Plain Object :

> An object in which the string keys represent one or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces, and the values represent a handler function to be called for the event(s).

You just need to verify that the events you're listening to are registered/appropriate events

Comment: Okay so I did what you say and I just have add this line in my function : $('.page-formulaire').css('height', '1300px'); But now, If I just click in the selecte for change the value without chose an option, it display the new css

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is it doing that you don't want it to? I didn't see this in your original question.

Comment: Okay so I have a first form who alow user to enter a code of a category, an AJAX request will return, in the select,the name of categories found. I want to make a second form with values from the category when he chose his category on the select or if he press enter of the keyboard, after enter the complete number.

Comment: I think you should post another question on StafkOverflow and try to be very clear about what code you have and what you want to do.

Comment: That's a different question. It sounds like you want/have an event handler for  the `Enter` keypress? If my answer doesn't answer your first question let me know and i'll delete it.

Comment: For me, if they press Enter, it's the same that if they submit he form. That's why I asked this. But maybe,  I'm wrong

Comment: So are you asking how to submit the form if they press `Enter`?

Comment: No, I just want to do this : If they submit the form or they select the category, I will make an another AJAX reqsuest. But just how to make the test.

Comment: I've editer my question. And no, because when I just click in the select field, it consider that I've changed the value of select. But I didn't selected something ...

Comment: When do you want the `select` to fire off an event? I'm confused.

Comment: When the user will select a category from the select, brought by an AJAX request after entering into the field, the code number of the category.

Comment: So only when there's a match in your database?

Comment: As you can see, my select is empty. When, the user write the begin of the code in the input, AJAX request complet the select with the option who contains different categories name whose code begin by the on entered by user. And it's when they select an option, that I want to perform a function

Comment: I've tried to update code like this : `$('option:not(#option-vide), #formulaire-uf').on('change submit', function()` but it no works too

Comment: Your selector looks incorrect. If they make a select and there's no value, why don't you just check for a value.....?